# About the value of $\prod\limits_{\ell=0}^j((k+1)^2-(\ell+1)^2)$ where one omits the factor $\ell=k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

I have a question regarding [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2905267/588260).
At one point, Alex Francisco writes at the end that $$\prod\limits_{\substack{0 \le \ell \le j \\ \ell \neq k}} ((k + 1)^2 - (\ell + 1)^2) = \dfrac{(-1)^{j - k}}{2(k + 1)^2} \cdot (j - k)!\, (j + k + 2)!$$

How did Alex Francisco do that?
And also why is there a 2 in the bottom? It seems as it disappears in the following step so maybe it's a typo?

I tried to expand and I didn't manage to get the same result, and I didn't find where the factor $2$ came from.

Comment: What about leaving a comment at Alex‘s answer and ask him for clarification?

Comment: @MartinR I think he disabled ping, I can't @ him . Also I think the proof of $\prod_{\substack{0 \le l \le j - i\\l ≠ k}} ((k + 1)^2 - (l + 1)^2) = \dfrac{(-1)^{j - i - k}}{2(k + 1)^2} \cdot (j - i - k)!\, (j - i + k + 2)!$ or $\prod_{\substack{0 \le l \le j - i\\l ≠ k}} ((k + 1)^2 - (l + 1)^2) = \dfrac{(-1)^{j - i - k}}{(k + 1)^2} \cdot (j - i - k)!\, (j - i + k + 2)!$ can be interesting for others.

Comment: If you start a comment on someone's post with that very someone's username ping, it gets removed automatically to save space, since notifications are automatic for such comments.

Comment: You accepted Alex's answer and awarded a 450 points bounty on it – without fully understanding the answer?

Comment: I thought I understood it fully, but when I tried to redo the proof, I found out that it wasn't as obvious as I thought, also the $2$ didn't ring a bell at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume $j \geq k$.
$$\prod\limits_{\substack{0 \le \ell \le j \\ \ell \neq k}} ((k+1)^2 -(l+1)^2) = \prod\limits_{\substack{0 \le \ell \le j \\ \ell \neq k}} (k-l)(k+l+2) = \frac{k! \cdot \prod\limits_{l=k+1}^j (k-l) \cdot \prod\limits_{l=0}^j (k+l+2)}{k+k+2} = \frac{(k+j+2)! \cdot (-1)^{j-k} \cdot (j-k)!}{2(k+1)^2} $$

Comment: I didn't understand the step 2->3, you seems to have split the product in some way, I recognize the (k-l) and (k+l+2) but not how k+k+2 and k! come from. And step 3->4, how did you simplified the products? When I try to compute a finite product of (a+k) on Wolfram Alpha, it keeps redirecting me to the rising factorial, is it linked?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be! Anyway, for 2->3 just split in the two obvious product and then divide the cases $l<k$ and $l>k$, if you merge the "non zero" ones adding the case $l=k$ you have to divide by it and obtain $k+k+2$. About 3->4 you should see that $k!$ times the last product in 3 is $\frac{(k+j+2)!}{k+1}$ and the rest is just $(-1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (k-j)$ (and of course $2(k+1)$ in the denominator).

Comment: Ok I got the thing about 2->3, the $(-1)^j-k$ and the factorials where does the two in$2(k+1)^2$ come from?

Comment: Because we had $k+k+2 = 2(k+1)$ in 3